# How can I get back to a login screen after a freeze?

Tags: command-line, 13.04, freeze, login-screen

I have to manually shut down and to enter my SDA crypt pass and my user pass over again.

How do I force the poweroff without having to hit the power button, or get back to a login screen. Nobody has answered this for multiple people.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> does nothing, my console is gone.

How can I get back to the login screen when ubuntu 13.04 freezes.

Comment: I would be alot more calm but this is the 50th time it's froze, and ALL I tried to do THIS TIME was open VLC, any little thing is causing an overload! This didn't happen in 12.04 for me D: Not ever to this degree and nobody anywhere on this website is answering anyones question for this and it's getting to be a big issue.

I'm to scared to even move my files from my external to 13.04 tbh.

Also thanks for the edit. Lol

Comment: I've had similar problems with 13.04. I don't consider it very stable yet.

Comment: been running xubuntu 13.04 since beta and it is very stable here, i would try to SSH into the frozen system and try the reboot command, after trying to see what happened, you can try the [REISUB](http://kember.net/articles/reisub-the-gentle-linux-restart/) thing, rarely works for me when it freezes

Comment: SSH into frozen system? Better exp please?

Also note: I can't reboot/restart ubuntu >.> I'm actually running it on a laptop that has no screen connected to a monitor because I broke it one day when I still had windows, that's when my friend showed me what linux was lmfao....

Comment: What make/model is your laptop, there may be certain driver/graphics (might explain the complete unresponsive freeze) issues with the new version, also does your keyboard have a "fn" key - this is often used to save space on keyboards - but you may need to use with "F1" (just a thought; unless ctrl+alt+F1 brings up tty1 normally)

Answer (score 2):

If it locks up completely, you can REISUB it, which is a safer alternative to just cold rebooting the computer.

REISUB by:

While holding Alt and the SysReq(Print Screen) keys, type R E I S U B.

R:  Switch to XLATE mode
E:  Send Terminate signal to all processes except for init
I:  Send Kill signal to all processes except for init
S:  Sync all mounted filesystems
U:  Remount filesystems as read-only
B:  Reboot

REISUB is BUSIER backwards, as in "The System is busier than it should be", if you need to remember it. Or mnemonically - R)eboot, E)ven, I)f, S)ystem, U)tterly, B)roken.